# Querying table based on associations value but not filtering them

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm wondering if it is possible to perform a query that filters a table based on the column of an association but still returns all the associations of the final results.

Here is a concrete example: I have apartments and *haveMany* occupants. I'd like to query the apartments based on the first or last name of any of the occupants. *But* once an apartment is found, id like all of its occupants (regardless of their names) to be returned.

```
models.Apartment.findAll({
    include: [{
        association: models.Apartment.associations.occupants,
        where: {
            $or: [
                { firstName: { $iLike: '%' + query + '%' } },
                { lastName: { $iLike: '%' + query + '%' } }
            ]
        }
    }]
})
```

Currently this finds the correct apartments but it also filters the occupants returned that match the criteria as well (leaving out the other occupants of the target apartment)

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!